# How do I change the URL of Add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I have WooCommerce site where I import the products via `AliDropShip Woo` directly from Aliexpress.com.
Now I am trying to change the 'Add to cart' behavior, bellow the code which changes the button name but I failed to get it redirect directly to Aliexpress.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );  

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
        return __( 'Visit the store', 'woocommerce' );
}

add_filter( 'product_add_to_cart_url', 'woo_store_cart_button_url' );  

function woo_store_cart_button_url() {
       return "https://aliexpress.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add your filter on `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect`

```
function _url_to_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.aliexpress.com/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', '_url_to_redirect' );
```

Though if you are setting up an affiliate sites, its better if you set set the products as "External or Affiliate" products

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/

Comment: It redirects me now to the dashboard. The reason I am not using External/ Affiliate option because the plugin will not auto update the products, and the variation data will be missing.